# Why does guard let x = x exhibit different scope behavior?

Tags: swift2, guard-statement

Why does guard let x = x inside a method behave differently than outside?

Example code below is copied right out of Playground.

```
var x:Int? = 3

func foo(x: Int?) {
    guard let x = x else {
        return
    }

     print(x)  // print "3\n"
}

foo(x)

guard let x = x else { 
  throw NSError(domain: "app", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
}

print(x)  // print "Optional(x)\n"
```

Answer (score 8):

`guard` statements require a `return`,`break`,`continue` or `throw` in their `else` clause. If you correct the optional in `x?.description` the compiler will point out this error. Using guard outside of the scope of a function makes no sense because it is meant to check for a condition and break out of that scope if it invalid. You will get the error:

> `guard` body may not fall through.

The only way for it to be valid in a playground (or outside the scope of a function) is to throw an error.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html):

> The else clause of a guard statement is required, and must either call
> a function marked with the noreturn attribute or transfer program
> control outside the guard statement’s enclosing scope using one of the
> following statements:
>
> - return
> - break
> - continue
> - throw

Comment: I am still seeing different scoping behavior with throw.  See edited post.

Comment: Swift folk confirmed this - apparently this is a compiler bug.